# Как нажимать кнопку не кликом, а с помощью скрипта?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, get

У меня есть две формы. В них по одной кнопке (`type="submit"`). Как по нажатию кнопки в одной форме активировать нажатие другой? Например, пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Отправить", и вслед за ней **автоматически** нажимается кнопка "Редактировать"(к примеру). Возможно, вопрос глупый, но вдруг это реально сделать? Не важно, каким способом, хоть JavaScript`ом, хоть PHP.
P.S. у одной формы метод GET, у второй - POST, если эта информация вдруг окажется полезной.

Comment: опишите, как это должно выглядеть для пользователя

Comment: @Igor Админ заходит во вкладку "Редактировать пользователя". Перед ним поля для ввода и в конце кнопка "Редактировать". После того, как он ввел поля и нажал на кнопку(GET), запускается скрипт, который изменит данные в таблице MySQL. Когда данные изменились, в этом же скрипте должна активироваться еще одна кнопка(POST)(не важно, будет она на странице сливаться с общим фоном или внутри скрипта), которая запишет в другую таблицу MySQL данные, что этот админ в такое-то время изменил данные о таком-то пользователе. У меня это реализовано, но, чтобы проделать эту операцию, нужно нажать две кнопки.

Answer (score 5):

В этом вопросе не правильно все. От темы вопроса, и до способа реализации.

1. Причем тут программный клик, если нужно отправить форму
2. Нельзя одновременно отправить две формы так как второй сабмит формы
   отменить отправку данных первым

Правильно было бы переписать бекенд часть чтоб не надо было такого выдумывать... но попробую помочь все равно. 
Клики не нужны.
Первую форму лучше отправить аяксом.

```
var form = $('#form1');
var form2 = $('#form2');
$.ajax({ 
    url: form.attr('action'), 
    type: form.attr('method'), 
    data: form.serialize() 
}).done( function(){ 
    // тут отправляем вторую форму
    form2.submit();
} );
```

Comment: под #form1 вы подразумевали форму с методом GET? и решит ли это мою проблему, если я хочу одновременно изменить данные в одной таблице MySQL и добавить данные о редактировании в другую(дата, человек, который редактировал и сам объект, который был изменен)?

Comment: Если вы хотите изменить данные в двух таблицах MySQL то почему вы эту проблему решаете на HTML. Разве нельзя поменять это во время отправки и обработки одной формы?

Comment: сначала так и хотел сделать, просто не дописал кое-что, поэтому напрасно подумал, что не работает. спасибо, что посоветовали еще раз попробовать)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('#sub-1').click(function(){ //при нажатии на первую кнопку
$('#sub-2').click(); //програмно нажимаем вторую кнопку
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input id="sub-1" type="submit" value="knopka 1"/>

<input id="sub-2" type="submit" value="knopka 2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: что-то не работает :( по отдельности кнопки по-прежнему выполняют свою работу, но если нажать на первую - вторая не активируется